# empty value when using statics - node Js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, postman, mern

**I am trying to store a user in MongoDB but when I send a test request from postman the req.body successfully logged to the console but MongoDB throw an error of empty values I put a function to test if I got any value in the statistic function but I got nothing back**

my schema :

```
{
 profilePicture: {
   type: String,
   required: true,
 },
 username: {
   type: String,
   required: true,
 },
 email: {
   type: String,
   required: true,
 },
 password: {
   type: String,
   required: true,
 },
},
{ timestamps: true }
);
```

my static function :

```
UserSchema.statics.signup = async function (
  profilePicture,
  username,
  email,
  password
) {
  const exist = await this.findOne({ username });

  if (exist) {
    throw Error("username exist");
  }

  if (!password || !profilePicture || !username || !email) {
    throw Error("missing");
  }

  // password are empty so hash don't work fix it first

  // const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
  // const hash = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);

  const user = await this.create({
    username,
    password,
    profilePicture,
    email,
  });

  return user;
};
```

```
const signupUser = async (req, res) => {
  const { profilePicture, username, email, password } = req.body;
  console.log(req.body);
  try {
    const user = await User.signup({
      profilePicture,
      username,
      email,
      password,
    });

    const token = createToken(user._id);

    res.status(400).json({ username, token });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(200).json({ error: error.message });
  }
};
```

**when I send a request from  postman I got the req.body working but it shows that the fields are empty this function run**

```
if (!password || !profilePicture || !username || !email) {
    throw Error("missing");
  }
```

**i use body-parser and send data from postman with the same key name**

Answer (score 1):

Your static function takes in four parameters, but you are calling it with a single object.

Try changing the `User.signup` call to:

```js
const user = await User.signup(
      profilePicture,
      username,
      email,
      password,
    );
```

(without the `{` and `}`).